# How to bind and save/update a inputcheckbox inside for loop in C# blazer

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor

Can any body help me to save multiple check box value with a input text box into db using C# blazor?
when i am trying to click any check box all the checkbox has been selected because i am having a single object, i am unable to figure out how to separate the object inside the loop and save it separately into db

my code something like this:

```html
@for (int i = 1; i
<=1 3; i++) { <div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
  <div class="form-check">
    <InputCheckbox class="form-check-input" @bind-Value="@testBenchIntilization.PT.PtSelected" /> @i<br />
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-8 mb-3">
    <label for="testname" class="control-label">Limit</label>
    <InputNumber for="testname" class="form-control" id="testname" placeholder="Test name" @bind-Value="@testBenchIntilization.PT.PtLimit" />
  </div>
  }
```

main class:

```
public class TestBenchIntilization
{
    [Required]
    public int TestId { get; set; }

    public TestBenchPressureTransducer PT{ get; set; } = new TestBenchPressureTransducer();
}
```

sub class:

```
public class TestBenchPressureTransducer
{
    public int  TestId { get; set; }
    public DateTime TestDate { get; set; }
    public string PtName { get; set; }
    public bool PtSelected{ get; set; }
        public float PtLimit { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: what's `testpt.PTList`?

Comment: and what do you mean with "help me to save ...into db"? Do you want us to write the db code as an answer? What's the real problem/question?

Comment: consider it    @for (int i = 1; i <= 13; i++)
                                        {
                                            <div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
                                                <div class="form-check">
                                                    <InputCheckbox class="form-check-input" @bind-Value="@testBenchIntilization.Solenoid1Selected" /> Pressure Sensor @i<br />
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        }

Comment: any reference would be helpful, because what is happening i am binding  with  @TestBenchIntilization.TestBenchPressureTransducer which is giving a single value only but i need to save seperate value for each check box

Comment: hope now you have better understanding

Comment: so you need to have a list of TestBenchPressureTransducer and bind to items within the list

Comment: Your first version with a List and `@foreach()` was much better.

Comment: Be clearer about what you want and what errors you got.

Comment: I agree that the first version with `@foreach()` and a list was better. But in both versions it remains unclear how certain variables are declared and it's unclear wether the missing code pieces are the problem.It's difficult to help if someone who wants to answer needs to figure out codelines to get a runnable example before they even can see the problem that was asked about. Therefore we usually require a [mre]. Please make sure to show a short example that could be pasted directly to a test project and clearly demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to copy the loop index. For exemple i must be copied into iCopy.

If you don't copy it then the value will be 3 = the value when the for is finished. The loop is in a lambda expression.

To understand why https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues/10768

Here is a simplified version based on your example.

```
    @page "/"

    <EditForm Model="@data" OnValidSubmit="@submit">
    @for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        int iCopy = i;
        <div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
            <div class="form-check">
                <InputCheckbox class="form-check-input" @bind-Value="@data[iCopy].selected" /> @(iCopy+1)<br />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8 mb-3">
            <label for="testname" class="control-label">Limit</label>
            <InputNumber for="testname" class="form-control" id="testname" placeholder="Test name" @bind-Value="@data[iCopy].limit" />
        </div>
    }
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</EditForm>

@(result)

@code{
    public class Test
    {
        public bool selected;
        public int limit;
    };

    string result = "";
    Test[] data = new Test[3];

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            data[i] = new Test();
    }

    void submit()
    {
        result = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            result += $"[{data[i].selected},{data[i].limit}],";
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no `[i]` to replace with `[iCopy]`.

Comment: Yes you have to copy i. I just modified the answer to add a link that explains why.

Comment: There is no `[i]` in the question.